# Iphone Caching Problem

Tags: iphone, caching, nsstring

when I call

```
-(IBAction)goback:(id)sender
{
    NSURL *xmlURL=[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://demo.komexa.com/sicherungsbereich.xml"];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:xmlURL cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData timeoutInterval:2];
    NSURLResponse *theResponse;
    NSError *theError;
    NSData *myRequestResult = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&theResponse error:&theError];
    NSString *stringReply = (NSString *)[[NSString alloc] initWithData:myRequestResult encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"reply from server: %@", stringReply);
}
```

with the Iphone , on the simulator it loads the String everytime really from the internet.But on the devices, it caches the String, so even if the content of http://demo.komexa.com/sicherungsbereich.xml changes (you can do that by calling http://demo.komexa.com) the String does not automatically reload new data.

Have you got an Idea?

I have uploaded the Code here,because of formatting problems:
http://demo.komexa.com/problem.txt

Comment: -(IBAction)goback:(id)sender

{

NSURL *xmlURL=[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://demo.komexa.com/sicherungsbereich.xml"];

NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:xmlURL cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData timeoutInterval:2];

NSURLResponse *theResponse;

NSError *theError;

NSData *myRequestResult = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&theResponse error:&theError];

NSString *stringReply = (NSString *)[[NSString alloc] 

initWithData:myRequestResult encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSLog(@"reply from server: %@", stringReply);
}

Comment: To format code, just select the block of code and press the button with the ones and zeroes or put 4 spaces before each line of code.

Comment: ok, thanks for your tip. Has anybody another idea how to get this out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just generate a random number and pass with your url , you get required result

e.g:

int randomNumber1 =  1 + arc4random()% 9;
    NSString *rstr = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%d",randomNumber1];

```
NSString *address = @"http://www.socialfactory.net/client-app/photovote/get_data.php";
NSString * nstr=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@?t=%@",address,rstr];
//NSURLRequest *theRequest=nil;
NSURLRequest *  theRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:nstr]];
NSURLResponse *resp = nil;
NSError *err = nil;
```

Comment: Yeah thats a idea, i have also done this in that way but that is not a good solution

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your Simulator and iPhone have different proxie settings. check this or try with the `NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData` policy which also ignores intermediate cachings. [See the docs here.](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLRequest_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy)

Comment: Unforunately NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData is not implemented, at least as of iOS v6